# "Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Workbook' failed" after running filepicker

Tags: excel, vba

For my Excel workbook i first have to import data from another sheet and then export worksheets from that workbook as .CSV files in a subfolder on the C:/ drive.
it used to work perfectly but suddenly it gave a Run-time error '1004'
if i import the data, save, close and re-open the excel file the export macro works, only after running the import macro i will get the error.

i tried both the `Application.GetOpenFilename` and the `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)` import methods, both will give the error.

Example of one of the export macro's:

```
Sub export_csv()
'
' csv2 Macro
'
  Dim ws As Worksheet

'

    Sheets(Array("5_CSV_Intermedian_Peptide", "5_CSV_Intermedian_MQ") _
        ).Select
    Sheets(Array("5_CSV_Intermedian_Peptide", "5_CSV_Intermedian_MQ") _
        ).Copy
   
    
    path = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\Export\"
    For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=path & "_" & ws.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False, local:=True
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False

Next
ActiveWorkbook.Close False
End Sub
```

summary of what i tried:

1. declare path as a string - did not work
2. fileformat:=xlCSV > fileformat:=6 - did not work
3. change `path = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\Export\"` to `path = "C:\Export\"` - did work but some PCs may have a different name for C:\ drive so is not preferred.
4. save, close and re-open the excel workbook after running the import macro - did work but not preferred for obvious reasons.
5. copy, paste values in, to be exported, worksheet as values - did not work
6. declare name of `ActiveWorkbook` before exporting - did not work
7. set value for path before copying the worksheets - does work but export does not end up in C:\

it seems to me as if the filepicker somehow screws up the location of the newly opened workbook with `worksheets.copy` and therefor the `activeworkbook.path` does not work

Edit: if i do it like this

```
Workbooks.Add
path = ActiveWorkbook.path
ActiveWorkbook.Close


Sheets(Array("5_CSV_Intermedian_Peptide", "5_CSV_Intermedian_MQ").Select
Sheets(Array("5_CSV_Intermedian_Peptide", "5_CSV_Intermedian_MQ").Copy
```

it works, but it really feels like a bandaid on a gaping wound to me
is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I am not sure where you want the `Export` subfolder to be located. If it the same folder where workbook with VBA code then change `ActiveWorkbook.path` to `ThisWorkbook.Path`. In your first code block `ActiveWorkbook` points to the new workbook with copied worksheets, so its `Path` property is an empty string.

Comment: sadly this is an inherited code from a previous employee. it is set up this way because the new workbook is pre-set to the windows drive (usually C:/)